# Frappe: Can we configure different number of workers for different types of Queue

Tags: erpnext, frappe

In `common_site_config` we have `background_workers` attribute. When we set this attribute to a certain value, that many number of workers are created per queue. In Frappe we have 3 queues, `short, long and default`. So if we set `background_workers:4` we get 4 workers for each of these 3 queues.

Is it possible to set number of workers for a specific queue, like, for short and default - 5 workers - so that load can be shared and run in parallel, for long - only 1 worker so that all the work on long queue can run in sequence.
Can we set number of workers per queue type?

Answer (score 1):

The values in the `common_site_config.json` file are used by bench to generate a corresponding `Procfile` (development) or `supervisor.conf` (production).

You can update the configuration files directly to fine tune these settings as per your needs. Checkout how supervisorctl (or honcho) works - their respective documentations.

The `supervisor.conf` file for your bench can be found under the config folder. After adding an additional section for your worker, a `bench restart` may be enough to setup your new workers.